# Flot bars outline

Tags: flot

I'm using a bar-chart to add a shaded range of expected values to my graph. The outline of the bars need to be removed to leave only the shaded region. Is this possible?

[image]
Thanking you in advance.

Comment: Apologies to those reading this... found it: bars: {lineWidth: 0}

Comment: Please post an answer to your question, then mark it as accepted, to make the answer a little more obvious to people who find it later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found my own solution...

```
bars: {lineWidth: 0}
```